# Does the main thread get control immediately after calling some thread's start() method?

Tags: java, multithreading

For example :

```
public class Example1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Loop loop = new Loop();
        loop.start(); //printing "Before start"
        System.out.println("After start");
    }
}
```

Can be a situation that the `loop`'s run method finishes before the execution of the last line that prints "After Start"?

Comment: Short answer: The main thread remains ready to run and, if there's at least one free core, will probably continue running without stopping. But you never know.

Comment: Even if the main thread was guaranteed to gain control it could lose control 1 instruction later.

Comment: @user704023 If any of the answers below have been able to give you more insight or have solved your problem then please consider marking one as the accepted answer so useful information becomes highlighted.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Once you start multi-threading, you would be wise to drop *all* assumptions you have about the order in which threads will run.

If it's important, you can use synchronizing operations but, without them, all bets are off.

Answer (score 11):

Yes, you have no control over how the threads are executed/scheduled by the JVM.

If you want to introduce some kind of ordering (execute the two threads in sequence) the most straightforward way to do it would be to use one of the `Lock` objects that Java provides.

Comment: Yes! Using an Executor would be way better, design-wise.

Answer (score 11):

You are basically asking about thread safety in Java (at least that is what I am understanding from the question). As one of the earlier answers already stated it is a good idea to drop any assumptions you may have about execution order when running multiple threads.

However(!), it is possible to use design principles and critical thinking to model your application in such a way that no undesired side effects can occur as a result of multi-threading.

For starters you can read this article on [Designing Object Initilization](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2076625/core-java/designing-object-initialization.html)
The gist of the article is that you should think of your classes as `finite state machines`. If you don't know what they are: `finite state machines` operate in a set of *states* (hence the name).

The idea is that when you are in state `(A)` you can define the behavior that this specific state can perform: `(A) -> (B), (A) -> (C)`
I can go from state `(A)` to state `(B)` and `(C)` but not to state `(D)` (should it exist) This mindset is important to understand what your application *CAN* do in any given situation. ([Fine State Machines Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite-state_machine))

Once you understand this you can move onto
**The Fix:**

There are three ways to make an object thread safe:

- Synchronize critical sections
- Make it immutable
- Use a thread-safe wrapper

Each approach has it's own advantages/disadvantages that are explained in Java documentation here:

- [Synchronize](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/syncmeth.html)
- [Immutables](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/imstrat.html)
- [Wrappers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/implementations/wrapper.html)

Hopefully this will have given you a better understanding of the complications you can face when creating multi-threaded applications.

Comment: This is a good answer, but it has a few annoying little errors, like odd capitalization and a somewhat patronizing tone ("if you can't be bothered to read it" is a prominent example)

Comment: The tone wasn't meant in a patronizing way but it has been duly noted, I rewrote the answer. I hope the information is now presented in a better way.

Answer (score 7):

If I add a join on the thread and a few more print statements then some of the characteristics can be explained.

```
public class Example1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Loop loop = new Loop();
        System.out.println("Before start");
        loop.start(); //printing "Before start"
        System.out.println("After start");
        loop.join();
        System.out.println("After join");
    }
}
```

"Before start" will *always* be printed before `loop.run()` gets executed.

"After join" will *always* be printed after `loop.run()` is finished.

"After start" has no guarantee about when it is printed relative to the `loop.run()`; it can be before, it can be after, it can be during execution interleaved with print statements in loop.run().

If you do want guarantees then you need other synchronization utilities like locks and semaphores.